# Problemas en la ejecución en mi la app al ofuscar código y subirla a Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, itextpdf, ofuscación

Mi aplicación se cierra cuando ejecuto la opción para visualizar el PDF, la aplicación ya se subió en la tienda, pienso que es un problema con el ofuscamiento y el iText7, ya que anteriormente lo había subido sin ofuscar y dio normal la opción para visualizar el PDF. Lo raro es que no me da ningún error, ya que al exportar en tipo apk e instalarlo al celular funciona normal, pero al exportar en tipo `.aab` y ofuscado ya no funciona. Ayuden por favor.

Aquí les dejo lo que cambie el antes y después:

NIVEL build.gradle: app -- ANTES DEL OFUSCAMIENTO, FUNCIONABA NORMAL

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false 
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap_info.txt'
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/*'
}
```

NIVEL build.gradle: app -- DESPUES DEL OFUSCAMIENTO, NO FUNCIONA

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true 
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap_info.txt'
    exclude 'com/itextpdf/io/font/cmap/*'
}
```

NIVEL build.gradle: project --

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:3.3.28'          // Must be before the Gradle Plugin for Android.
    //noinspection GradlePluginVersion
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:X.Y.Z' // Your current AGP version.
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay que tener cuidado a ofuscar el código, algunas clases que regularmente son de librería de terceros pueden perder su funcionalidad.

Lo que puedes realizar es identificar y excluir las clases para que estas no sean ofuscadas, esto lo puedes realizar dentro de tu archivo `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-keep class packageName.subPackageName.** { *; }
```

---

por ejemplo, tengo varías clases de un SDK que no funcionan al ofuscar mi código:

```
import com.appnexus.opensdk.BannerAdView
import com.appnexus.opensdk.ANClickThroughAction
import com.appnexus.opensdk.AdListener
import com.appnexus.opensdk.AdView
import com.appnexus.opensdk.NativeAdResponse
import com.appnexus.opensdk.ResultCode
```

para excluirlas usaré dentro de mi archivo `proguard-rules.pro` la siguiente instrucción:

```
-keep public class com.appnexus.opensdk.** {public *;}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funcionó. Algo más que aprendí. Sabía que ese era el problema pero no sabía como podría solucionarlo.

Comment: Excelente @adddddddb , :-) saludos!